# Can not launch Google Play Store app in some devices?

Tags: android, google-play

I have implemented code as follow for launching Google Play Store app.

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName();
try {
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

It works properly in some mobile devices. However, can not work properly in some ones. They launch the browser, even they have the Google Play Store app.

And more weird, I have tried to click Admob banner in the trouble device. It indeed launches the Google Play Store app.

I have no idea what I met. Please help me if you know how to solve it.

Comment: Use [App Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.japanesecrackers.appbrowser) to examine the manifest of whatever is claiming to be the Play Store app.

Comment: thx. It is interesting app. I see the manifest XML. But, I have no idea how I can examine  "whatever is claiming to be the Play Store app" in the informations?

Comment: Well, either it has an `<intent-filter>` matching your desired `Uri` values, or it does not.

Comment: no. Even the manifest xml has not the desired Uri in the device that works well.